# Nomes de funções em php, como decora-las?

Tags: php

Há tempos que tento decorar o nome de varias funções em php, mas não tem jeito, acabo esquecendo tudo.

> "Esta função é tudo junto ou tem um underline?"

Exemplos:

```
ucfirst ou uc_first?
strval ou str_val?
```

Há também funções que fica bastante difíceis de decorar somente deduzindo sua escrita em inglês como:

```
ltrim
strcasecmp
strcoll
strtr
```

Queria saber se vocês tem dicas de como decora-las mais facilmente....

Comment: Embora pareça tenho minhas dúvidas se isto realmente é um pergunta sobre programação. Está mais para um problema de memorização e o *site* não está repleto em neurocientistas ou outros profissionais que trabalham com isto. Qualquer resposta será opinião de leigo. Eu poderia dizer, por exemplo, para usá-las muitas vezes mesmo que artificialmente, vai acabar decorando.

Comment: Ah, até que enfim alguém questionou sobre essa incoerência do PHP!

Comment: Infelizmente não existe nenhum tipo de padrão tanto para nome de funções quanto para ordem de parâmetros. O ideal é usar um IDE com auto complete e ter sempre o manual do PHP por perto.

Comment: lido com php desde 2000. Até hoje me confundo em relação a ordem dos parâmetros das funções... rsrsr e nunca lembro ao certo se strpos é junto ou str_pos separado, por exemplo.. na dúvida apenas digito no google... Acho bobagem querer decorar tudo.. é para isso que existe o manual.

Comment: Depende de vc. Se vc acha mas facil escrever minhafuncaquecriaavalor() oi Mfccav() ou MinhaFuncaoQueCriaAValor() ou Minha_Funcao_Que_Cria_A_Valor(), não importa. O único problema e o numero e valores dos parâmetros, e se lembrar do nome. Para isso, a única solução e ter uma documentação 'no papel'.